# Start asp.net WebApi project from WPF project within solution using OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a .NET solution which has two projects:

1. WPF project for the WPF application
2. ASP.NET WebApi project with a few controllers

I want to host the WebApi inside my WPF application (using OWIN). Any idea how can I do this?

If I create my controllers in the WPF project itself then I can host them using WebApp.Start (and pass a config class).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to make a desktop application with OWIN and WebApi http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869223/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Create-a-Self-Hosted-OWIN-Based-We

It's true that it's a console based application but you could use that in the bootstrap of your application to start the OWIN server when the app starts.

I would also advise trying it in a new test project until you get a hang of it before starting to create api controllers and mapping out routes

Comment: I've tried to do this and it works, if the controllers and the webapi config are in the same project (namespace). Now, I have a separate project for WebApi (it has it's own WebApiConfig and RouteConfig). Now when I specify Routes in MapHttpRoute method, how do I tell it that controllers are in a different project? 
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}");

Comment: For routing i recommend using the webapi routing attributes, would make your life a bit more easier that using the routing config file, you can see an example here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Start reading documentation. Then "just go". This (self-hosting) is exactly what OWIN was designed to do and it is all documented.

IN your app at one point you will configure and start an OWIN based server. Contrary to how you do normal web apps, you can abandon the WebApi project - all controllers etc. can live in an assembly. Reflection is used to find them.